# How to present data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, alert, prompt

I have a bookmarklet that extract email addresses from a site. it returns lets say 10 email addresses. how can I present them to a user to make them copy-and-paste-able? I cannot use alert, because you cannot copy text from alert. I cannot use prompt, because it makes them unreadable. I cannot use document.write, because I want to not change the window. I cannot create new window, because it might be blocked by pop-up blocker. is there any other way to do this and make it universal?

Comment: You can copy/paste from an alert by simply doing ctrl-a, ctrl-c. You won't see your selection, but it does work. Also, Why not add a div, position it absolute on the top right corner? The page won't be any different from it.

Comment: position fixed is preferred because position absolute is from the first parent which has a position. In that way you can make a lightbox effect with no problems.

Comment: @Nanne that will work in all browser? even IE6?

Comment: @khael : you're absolutely right, I used the word absolute without any thought, but should've used fixed. My bad. (@IAdapter: what do you mean? copy paste is an OS feature afaik, position should work in any CSS capable broswer)

Comment: @Nanne I have never used copying text from alert, so I'm shocked that its possible. so its windows only? does it work in all browsers?

Comment: @Nanne it doesn't work from firebug. I did alert('a') and when I tired to do it your way it did not work.

Comment: It does here, maybe you run a different OS then me :)

Comment: @IAdapter Just create a new `div` and place your data there is the most usefull thing to do. You add User friendliness to your site in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes make a new `div` or `textarea` using `document.createElement` put them there and after an ok just delete the node.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could introduce a `div` tag with an ID (let's say "a") which would initially be blank.

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

And then later on use `document.getElementById` tag to change its inner HTML.

```
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=email_id1+"<br>"+email_id2+"<br>"+email_id3;
```

You wouldn't need to refresh the page. It would be updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can put email id's in textboxes like,

```
$('textbox').val(email_id1+
            '\n'+email_id2+
            '\n'+email_id3+
            '\n'+email_id4+
            '\n'+email_id5+
            '\n'+email_id6+
            '\n'+email_id7+
            '\n'+email_id8+
            '\n'+email_id9+
            '\n'+email_id10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery dialog. You can destroy it when user closes.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/